# Mac Guest (virtual-machine) can't disable big display scaling

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, macos-highsierra

The problem is described on the animated gif: https://media.giphy.com/media/3oFzmnDa3LdMZue8Du/giphy.gif

so I'm trying to reset Mac guest resolution to normal but it scales everything and it becomes so big (text, windows, icons)

So I click on **Default for Display**:

[image: image 1 - enter image description here]

it sets resolution normally but only for 1 second:

[image: image 2 - enter image description here]

but after one seconds it automatically gets back to scaled option:

[image: image 3 - enter image description here]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Answer (score 0):

solved by installing fixed vmware tools (darwin.iso) https://cloud.mail.ru/public/A7JK/aLucXbP1N